# Geometric interpretation of the fact that $\langle y\rangle +\langle y-f(x) \rangle$ is radical iff $f$ is square-free

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I aim to find a geometric way to see when we can have the sum of two ideals $\langle y\rangle$ and $\langle y-f(x)\rangle$ is a radical ideal. To do this, I think maybe I need to find some geometric relationship between $\langle y\rangle$ and $\langle y-f(x)\rangle$.

I have just managed to shown that $\langle y\rangle+\langle y-f(x)\rangle$ is radical iff $f$ is square-free. But I wonder how could the fact "square-free" intepreted geometrically. Could someone please help to give some visualization? Any hint or links are also appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: $(y)$ corresponds to the hypersurface $y=0$ and $(y-f(x))$ to $y=f(x)$. The sum of the ideals to their intersection $0=y=f(x)$. The lack of squares corresponds to the intersection being transversal, like $0=y=x$.

Comment: @Marja Thank your for your explanation. So could the fact be explained as: We are looking for the intersection of $y=0$ and $y=f(x)$. That is, we are looking at the points on the x-axis such that $f(x)=0$. As $f$ is square free, we have no multiple roots, so on each point of these intersections, the graph of $f(x)$ transverse the x-axis, so the x-axis is not the tangent of the graph at any point? Am I correct?